# Error: "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" (even with Microsoft 365 subscription)

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to get the events from outlook calendar but I get an error doing so. I have an app registered on Azure Portal (free plan), which I'm using to read the events with Nodejs. This are the permissions I've set in order to be able to query the Microsoft Graph API:

[ApiPermissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2573.png)

Using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid profile offline_access&state=12345` I've been able to get a {code} which I'm using to redeem an access token using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` with this body parameters:

```
{
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": "{code}",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:3000",
    "client_id": "{clientId}",
    "client_secret": "{clientSecret}",
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid profile offline_access"
}
```

I believe that the scope of this token is also suitable for what I need:

[TokenError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpQSQ.png)

When I try to make a request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/users` or even `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/997f56e7-06b6-44ad-be6a-3cc7377ae54a/users/{userId}`, I get the users data without problems. The response looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "My Display Name",
    "givenName": "My Name",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": "en",
    "surname": "My Surname",
    "userPrincipalName": "...@....onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-..."
}
```

But when I make a request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/users/{userId}/calendars` I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid '\[tenantGuid\]' does not exist.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"bf9e026f-6160-4975-8952-1796d0903882","oAuthEventcV":"tiG/jGvOvqjHEw5i0jde2Q.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant%22,%22requestId%22:%22b274ff09-22e7-48ff-abfa-1703c90ad358%22,%22date%22:%222023-03-28T07:42:17"}}}
```

I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Also, I did an extensive search about this error and I found that I needed a Microsoft 365 subscription, so I bought one. I currently have the Microsoft 365 personal plan.

And I added the Office 365 Management APIs permissions on Azure Portal.

I still have the same issue, do I need to set up the tenant again? Do I need to change something in the configuration or am I missing something? Maybe I don't have the right subscription, do I need a Microsoft 365 Business subscription? How can I solve it?

What's interesting is that when I try to make the exact same requests using the Microsoft Graph Explorer it works as expected. And if I use the token given there in Access token tab in my backend it works as well, so I believe the problem is with the token I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **auth code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, scopes are present:

[image]

Using the above generated access token, I am able to fetch the calendar details successfully like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/users/{userId}/calendars
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if the license is missing in your tenant to perform the action.

To resolve the error, subscribe O365 license and assign **O365 license** to the users like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check the below:

- Check whether you are passing correct TenantID.
- Make use of organizations/common endpoint if you are calling other tenant users.
- Otherwise, try configuring another tenant and check.

Comment: Facing the similar kind of issue,
The images you uploaded seem to be not visible.

Can you possibly re-upload?

Will be of great help!